# Dynamically edit lists within a csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, sed, awk

I have a csv file that looks like that:

```
col1|col2

1|a
2|g
3|f

1|m
3|k
2|n

2|a
1|d
4|r
3|s
```

where `|` separates the columns, and would like to transform it into something homogeneous like:

```
------------------------
fields  >    1  2  3  4
record1      a  g  f
record2      m  n  k
record3      d  a  s  r
------------------------
```

Is there a way to do that? What would be better, using mysql or editing the csv file?

Comment: Do you really have an empty line between each data line or are you just fighing with the SO editor?

Comment: fighting *wide smile*

Comment: do you really need those text "record1,2.." or "fields > 1234" in your output

Comment: " | " was just a graphic example, meaning the separation between columns, probably misleading. I need 1,2,3,4 as fields names (top of column) in the output file. I thought record 1,2.. would be useful to have as a unique id for the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an awk solution:

```bsh
BEGIN{
    RS=""
    FS="\n"
}
FNR==NR&&FNR>1{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,d,"|")
        if (d[1] > max)
            max = d[1]
    }
    next
}   
FNR>1&&!header{
    printf "%s\t","fields  >"
    for (i=1;i<=max;i++)
        printf "%s\t",i
    print ""
    header=1
}
FNR>1{    
    printf "record%s\t\t",FNR-1

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,d,"|")
        val[d[1]] = d[2]    
    }

    for (i=1;i<=max;i++)
        printf "%s\t",val[i]?val[i]:"NULL"
    print ""

    delete val
}
```

Save as `script.awk` and run like *(notice it uses a two pass approach so you need to give the file twice)*:

```bsh
$ awk -f script.awk file file
fields  >       1       2       3       4
record1         a       g       f       NULL
record2         m       n       k       NULL
record3         d       a       s       r
```

Adding the line `5|b` to the first record in `file` gives the output:

```bsh
$ awk -f script.awk file file
fields  >       1       2       3       4       5
record1         a       g       f       NULL    b
record2         m       n       k       NULL    NULL
record3         d       a       s       r       NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! do you think it is possible to print "NULL" when a field isn't populated?

Comment: +1. FWIW I would set FS="\n" as that's the usual thing to do when RS="" and then you don't need that n=split($0,line,/\n/).

Comment: @sudo_O - the thing is, you can't produce exactly the output the OP wants without 2 passes of the data since the number of columns in the formatted output header has to be the max number of fields across all records. I posted something to produce the output in the END section.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I thought about doing something similar but since you got there first I'll just print the field count as a footer instead. Note your answer doesn't non-continuous data, for instance add `5|b` to first record.

Comment: @sudo_O - good point, I was working off the number of fields instead of the numeric values preceding the "|"s. I've fixed it now and posted the updated version with your suggested change to the input file. Thanks.

Comment: @sudo_O i am working on it, no version including the "NULL" part seems to work for me. I am un-elegantly editing the csv file and populating THERE the empty cells with NULL. Thank you very much for your help, i am pretty sure i can finish what i started now.

Comment: @Sergiof4 - if none of the answers here is working for you then either your input file is corrupt or your awk is broken. It would be well worth your time figuring out which now rather than wasting your time hand-editing the csv file and then having to do the same again next time.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it's my first day here. Not sure what you mean by "(notice it uses a two pass approach so you need to give the file twice)".

Comment: The awk script needs to read the input file twice so you give the file twice *i.e* `awk -f script.awk file file` The first read is to count the maximum numbers of fields as displayed in the header and the second pass todo the real work.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this, works for your example: **gawk** is required

```
awk -F'|' -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)a[$i]=$(i+1);asorti(a,d);
for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s", a[d[i]]((i==length(a))?"":" ");delete a;delete d;print ""}' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat file

1|a
2|g
3|f

1|m
3|k
2|n

2|a
1|d
4|r
3|s
kent$  awk -F'|' -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)a[$i]=$(i+1);asorti(a,d);
for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s", a[d[i]]((i==length(a))?"":" ");delete a;delete d;print ""}' file
a g f
m n k
d a s r
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I am having a syntax error. PC-SERGIO:~/Scrivania/a$ awk -F'|' -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)a[$i]=$(i+1);asorti(a,d);
> > for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s", a[d[i]]((i==length(a))?"":" ");delete a;delete d;print ""}' 12.csv
awk: linea progr.:1: > for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s", a[d[i]]((i==length(a))?"":" ");delete a;delete d;print ""}
awk: linea progr.:1: ^ syntax error

Comment: @kent You should replace the calls to `length(a)` with `n` where `n=asorti(a,d)`

Comment: +1 but not sure whey you need to sort anything, just keep track of max and loop from 1.

Comment: @EdMorton thx. I am not sure the "ids" are continued or not. OP didn't say it. that's why I made it a bit complicated. sudo_O, you are right, should get length() once from asorti(). Sergiof4, I don't know why it didn't work (syntax error) by you. I just tested again, it worked with your example file. well the col1|col2 header I ignored, also the output, those headers if they are fixed string, it would be easy to added.

Comment: @Sergiof4 - notice the spurious ">" symbols in your comment. Maybe that's the issue? Maybe you aren't using gawk (in which case asorti() isn't available and you can't delete a whole array)? Try awk --version.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
col1|col2

1|a
2|g
3|f
5|b

1|m
3|k
2|n

2|a
1|d
4|r
3|s
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
fields >    1    2    3    4    5
record1     a    g    f NULL    b
record2     m    n    k NULL NULL
record3     d    a    s    r NULL
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ RS=""; FS="\n" }

NR>1 {
   ++numRecs

   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      split($i,fldNr2val,"|")
      fldNr = fldNr2val[1]
      val   = fldNr2val[2]

      recNrFldNr2val[numRecs,fldNr] = val

      numFlds = (fldNr > numFlds ? fldNr : numFlds)
   }
}

END {
   printf "fields >"
   for (fldNr=1;fldNr<=numFlds;fldNr++) {
      printf " %4s", fldNr
   }
   print ""

   for (recNr=1; recNr<=numRecs; recNr++) {
      printf "record%d ", recNr
      for (fldNr=1;fldNr<=numFlds;fldNr++) {
         printf " %4s", ((recNr,fldNr) in recNrFldNr2val ? recNrFldNr2val[recNr,fldNr] : "NULL")
      }
      print ""
   }
}
```